# Prevent bubbling/capturing when using custom react component on leaflet map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I am using `React Leaflet` and put my own custom component on top of it. To keep this on topic, I will just use examples to reduce fluff from other code.

The problem is that when double clicking, or dragging over the text in the input it interacts with the map and causes zoom or drag to happen on the map. I do not want that!

I am adding the proper methods to prevent bubbling/capturing, but I know react has synthetic events and those may work differently?? I have the styling to where it is placed over the map with position absolute with a high index. It shows up just fine so that is why I'm not using the MapControl class and extending it.

The input is nothing more than a basic input component:

```
import React from 'react'

export default function Search(){
  // stop bubbling/capturing not working
  const stopPropagation = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation()
    e.preventDefault()
  }

  return (
  <div onClick={stopPropagation} onDoubleClick={stopPropagation}>
    <input onClick={stopPropagation} onDoubleClick={stopPropagation} type="text" />
  </div>
 )
}
```

The Map component, only thing here is to see I am using the `Map` and passing the `Search` comp as a child:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Map, TileLayer } from 'react-leaflet'

export default function Map() {
  return (
   <Map
    bounds={initBounds}
    maxZoom={30}
    onMoveend={handleMove}
    ref={mapEl}
   >
    <Search />
    <TileLayer 
        attribution='&amp;copy <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        url='https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
    />
</Map>
 )
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason that `<Search>` has to be a child of the map?  If not, move it outside the map component and that should solve the issue.

Comment: Hey bro, did you find the solution? I am also facing the same issue. I created the [issue in the `react-leaflet` repo](https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/issues/765).

Comment: I did @Tekson I'll post an answer!

Answer (score 4):

You can use the leaflet `disableClickPropagation` method to disable bubbling/capturing.

```js
import L from from 'leaflet'

// Inside your component where the input is

// ...
import { useRef, useEffect } from 'react'

const ref = useRef()

useEffect(() => {
        if(ref?.current){
            const disableClickPropagation = L?.DomEvent?.disableClickPropagation
            disableClickPropagation(ref.current)
        }

}, [])

return (
  <div ref={ref}>...</div>
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, This helps me a lot. You can accept your answer now.